# spring integration increase performance

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

I have been running a program to read a file having 6 million rows and validate each line and write the string containing the validation message to an output file. I am using spring integration to achieve that as well as invoking spring batch from spring integration using spring batch-integration adapters. Spring batch invoked from spring integration completes in 47s whereas the processing done entirely in spring integration takes close to 3 mins. My goal is to identify ways to improve my spring integration code to perform close to the spring batch performance. Here is how my spring integration project looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:batch-int="http://www.springframework.org    /schema    /batch-integration"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch-integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch-integration/spring-batch-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream">

<context:annotation-config />
<import resource="classpath*:/spring/batch/jobs/response-job.xml" />
<import
    resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/integration/integration-bean-config.xml" />

<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.foo.integration.framework" />
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="inputFileChannel"
    directory="file:#{systemProperties['input.tsm.file.watcher.directory']} "
    channel="filesChannel" />
<int:poller id="tsmFilePoller" max-messages-per-poll="100"
    fixed-rate="1000" default="true" />

<int:channel id="filesChannel">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="inputLogger" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="inputLogger"
    level="DEBUG" expression="payload.toString()"
    logger-name="org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler"></int:logging-channel-adapter>
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="errorLogger"
    level="DEBUG"></int:logging-channel-adapter>


<int:router input-channel="filesChannel"
    expression="payload.getName().substring(payload.getName().lastIndexOf('.'))">
    <int:mapping value=".dat" channel="datFileChannel" />
    <int:mapping value=".txt" channel="errorFileChannel" />
    <int:mapping value=".csv" channel="tsmBatch" />
</int:router>

<int:channel id="errorFileChannel">
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="datFileChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter
    channel="errorFileChannel"
    directory="file:#{systemProperties['incorrect.tsm.file.drop.directory']} "
    auto-create-directory="true"></int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="tsmBatch"></int:channel>
<int:transformer id="fileToBatchTransformer" ref="tsmToBatchJobTransformerBean"
    input-channel="tsmBatch" method="toRequest" output-channel="invokeJob" />
<int:channel id="invokeJob"></int:channel>

<batch-int:job-launching-gateway
    request-channel="invokeJob" job-launcher="jobLauncher" reply-channel="nullChannel"></batch-int:job-launching-gateway>


<int:splitter output-channel="channel5" input-channel="channel3">
    <bean
        class="com.foo.integration.framework.splitter.FileSplitter" />
</int:splitter>
<int:channel id="channel3"></int:channel>
<int:channel id="channel5">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="executor" />
</int:channel>

<int:chain input-channel="channel5" output-channel="preServiceChannel">

    <int:aggregator correlation-strategy-expression="headers['fileName']"

        release-strategy-expression="size() == 3000"
        expire-groups-upon-completion="true" send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
        message-store="firstMessageStore"></int:aggregator>

</int:chain>

<int:channel id="preServiceChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="postServiceChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>
<int:service-activator ref="tsmServiceActivator"
    input-channel="preServiceChannel" method="handleMessage"
    output-channel="postServiceChannel">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="1"
        time-unit="MILLISECONDS" task-executor="executor"></int:poller>
</int:service-activator>

<int:chain input-channel="postServiceChannel">

    <int:header-enricher>

        <int:header name="processed" method="computeValue"
            ref="postHeaderEnrichingBean" />
    </int:header-enricher>
    <int:aggregator id="fileMsgAggregator"
        correlation-strategy-expression="headers['processed']"
        release-strategy-expression="size() == 3000"
        send-partial-result-on-expiry="true" message-store="messageStore"
        expire-groups-upon-completion="true"> <!-- release-strategy-expression="size() == 3000" -->
    </int:aggregator>
    <int:transformer method="transform" ref="payloadEnricher"></int:transformer>

    <int-file:outbound-channel-adapter
        id="validationService"
        directory="file:#{systemProperties['validation.error.tsm.file.drop.directory']} "
        auto-create-directory="true" filename-generator-expression="'TSMValidationsErrorMsgFile.dat'"
        mode="APPEND">
    </int-file:outbound-channel-adapter>
</int:chain>

<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="20"
    queue-capacity="0" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />

<bean id="firstMessageStore"
    class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore" />
<bean id="firstReaper"
    class="org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupStoreReaper">
    <property name="messageGroupStore" ref="firstMessageStore" />
    <property name="timeout" value="40000" />
</bean>
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="firstReaper" method="run"
        fixed-rate="20000" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>


<int:header-enricher input-channel="datFileChannel"
    output-channel="channel3">
    <int:header name="fileName" method="computeValue" ref="headerEnrichingBean" />
</int:header-enricher>

<bean id="headerEnrichingBean"
    class="com.foo.integration.framework.enricher.MessageHeaderEnricher" />
<bean id="postHeaderEnrichingBean"
    class="com.foo.integration.framework.enricher.PostMessageHeaderEnricher" />
<int:channel id="channel3"></int:channel>
<bean id="messageStore"
    class="org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore" />
<bean id="reaper"
    class="org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupStoreReaper">
    <property name="messageGroupStore" ref="messageStore" />
    <property name="timeout" value="30000" />
</bean>
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="reaper" method="run" fixed-rate="20000" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>


<bean id="payloadEnricher"
    class="com.foo.integration.framework.enricher.TSMPayloadEnricher" />

</beans>
```

STS Structure:
[image]

I am splitting the input file row by row using an iterator and passing it to an aggregator which will group the records in size of 3000 and pass to service-activator which does the row validation and sends the output to another aggregator which aggregates the output and writes it to an output file.

I would really appreciate if someone could give me pointers on where I could executor or remove executor to enhance the performance. Please let me know if you need any more info. Thanks and Have a blessed day.

Comment: Use a profiler to spot the bottlenecks in your application. Then, start tuning it.

Comment: If this is working code for which you want advice on improvements, then https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a more appropriate place to post this. Stack Overflow is for code that is having issues such that it does not function as intended.

Comment: I have added the question in  codereview.stackexchange.com as per your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: @Luiggi, I used Java Mission Control to profile the process, but have not been successful in identifying the bottleneck so far.

Comment: You have an input poller that's explicitly rate-limited...

Comment: thanks Chrylis. I am new to spring Integration. can you explain  what the problem could be with the poller config? Initially I had the max-messages-per-poll as 10000 and that didnt help either

Comment: Vinod, You can add JMX port, expose spring integration components using MBeanExporter and then use JVisualVM to monitor different components and their processing time

Comment: this is how you can expose <jmx:mbean-exporter domain="my.company.domain" mbean-server="mbeanServer"/>

 <bean id="mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
     <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true"/>
 </bean>